How to start MongoDB Service on windows with IP
I had a problem with MongoDB service in windows, so I want to start the service but by default the service runs on 127.0.0.1, and you cant connect to it from outside the machine.
How can I run the MongoDB Service on My server IP?

Solution that I could not found on internet by searching (maybe I was not searching on right subject) But:
The command that runs the MongoDB Service is
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service

You can see that the --config reads the config from mongod.cfg file,
So the only thing I needed to do is just change the IP inside that file.
The file has a section like:
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: {YOUR IP}


Your answer is correct. Instead of your IP you can also use 0.0.0.0 or set bindIpAll: true
